# Show that the Quotient map is closed.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Let $X \cup Y$ be the space with disjoint union topology.Suppose $A \subset X, A $ closed, $f : A \to Y$ be a continuous closed map.Consider the quotient map $\pi: X \cup Y \to X \cup _{f} Y$.Then $\pi$ is closed map.

I am trying to prove using the definitions directly but its getting bit messy.Is there any 'smart' way to prove $\pi$ is closed?

Comment: If $F \subset X \cup Y$ is closed, a) what does that mean, and b) what is $\pi^{-1}(\pi(F))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following diagram let the map $A \hookrightarrow X$ and the maps to $X \cup Y$ be the inclusions. The maps $\bar f$ and $j: Y \hookrightarrow X \cup_f Y$ send a point to its equivalence class, so the outer rectangle and the triangles commute. Note that closedness of $\pi$ is equivalent to closedness of both $\bar f$ and $j$, so showing that each of these two maps is closed is maybe less messy.

[image]

Consider closed sets $B \subseteq X$ and $C\subseteq Y$. You need to show that $\pi^{-1}(\bar f(B))$ and $\pi^{-1}(j(C))$ are closed in $X \cup Y$. For either set, there exists a simple formula from which you should see, using closedness of $A$ and of $f$ whenever needed, that the set is closed. Can you find them? Let me know if you struggle and I'll provide some hints.

Comment: Sorry..I really don't see why the claimed sets are closed probably because my knowledge to ad junction spaces is very limited.Could you please explain more?

Comment: You have $\pi^{-1}(\bar f(B))  = B \cup f(B\cap A) \cup f^{-1}(f(B\cap A))$. Do you see why this set is closed? For $\pi^{-1}(j(C))$ there is a similar formula @VictorBarg

Comment: Using the continuity of $f$ and Closedness of $f$ its clear to me that the set is closed.But i dont actually see how do you get that formula ?Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: @VictorBarg No problem. Can you at least show one inclusion, like 
$$
\pi^{-1}(\bar f(B))  \supseteq B \cup f(B\cap A) \cup f^{-1}(f(B\cap A))
$$
Here you need to show that when you apply $\pi$ to any of the three sets on the right, you end up in $\bar f(B)$. I demonstrate how to show that $\pi(f(B\cap A))$ is in $\bar f(B)$: Take a point $b \in B\cap A$. Then $\pi(f(b)) = j(f(b)) = \bar f(b)$, so $\pi(f(b))$ is in $\bar f(B)$. For the other two sets, the method is similar.

Comment: The inclusion
$$
\pi^{-1}(\bar f(B))  \subseteq B \cup f(B\cap A) \cup f^{-1}(f(B\cap A))
$$
is trickier, though. But before we come to this one, let's deal with the other inclusion first and make sure it is clear.

Comment: This inclusion is clear. The containment of $B$ and $f(B \cap A)$ in RHS is much easier than the containment of $(f^{-1}(f(B \cap A)))$ which you have described .Could you explain the reverse inequality?Thank you.

Comment: @StefanHamcke, how you built this diagram?

Comment: @RafaelHolanda: Using the package `tikz` in Latex. Here is the code http://pastebin.com/y2HWf50r

Comment: @VictorBarg So assume $x \in X \cup Y$ satisfies $\pi(x) \in \bar f(B)$. If $x$ is in $X$, then this means $\bar f(x) \in \bar f(B)$, so there is a $b\in B$ such that $\bar f(x) = \bar f(b)$, in other words, $x$ and $b$ are identified. For $x\notin A$, this implies $x=b$, thus $x\in B$, and for $x\in A$, it implies $b\in A$ and $f(x) = f(b)$, thus $x \in f^{-1}(f(B\cap A))$.

Comment: If, however, $x$ is a point of $Y$, then $\pi(x)\in\bar f(B)$ means there is a $b\in B$ such that $j(x) = \bar f(b)$. Again, this means $x$ and $b$ are identified via the relation defining the space $X \cup_f Y$, so $x$ must be an element of $f(A)$, and there it must be $f(b)$, as that is the only point in $Y$ which is identified to $b$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke I see.Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for my silly question and troubling you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. And don't be ashamed of your questions, it is normal to have quite some problems when you first learn a topic. Don't forget to also figure out the formula for $\pi^{-1}(j(C))$, which is actually simpler than the formula for $\pi^{-1}(\bar f(B))$. @VictorBarg

Answer (score 2):

I would just follow the definitions. Suppose that $F\subseteq X\cup Y$ is closed. Then $F$ is the disjoint union of the sets $F_0=(F\cap X)\setminus A$, $F_1=F\cap A$, $F_2=(F\cap Y)\setminus f[A]$, and $F_3=F\cap f[A]$.

- Show that $\pi^{-1}[\{\pi(z)\}]=\{z\}$ if $z\in F_0\cup F_2$.
- Show that $\pi^{-1}[\{\pi(z)\}]=f^{-1}[\{f(z)\}]\cup\{f(z)\}$ if $z\in F_1$.
- Show that $\pi^{-1}[\{\pi(z)\}]=f^{-1}[\{z\}]\cup\{z\}$ if $z\in F_3$.
- Conclude that $\pi^{-1}\big[\pi[F]\big]=F\cup f^{-1}\big[f[F\cap X]\big]\cup f^{-1}[F\cap Y]$, which is closed (why?).

Comment: Thank you..Could you please explain why $F$ is union of $F_i$'s ? I know that a set $F$ in $X \cup Y$ is closed iff $F \cap X$ and $F \cap Y$ is closed in $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Comment: @Victor: Every point of $X\cup Y$ belongs to exactly one of the four sets $A$, $X\setminus A$, $f[A]$, and $Y\setminus f[A]$; I’ve simply applied that to $F$ by intersecting each of those four sets with $F$.

Comment: Yeah.Just now i also realized that.Btw,it it true that closed set in $X \cup Y$ is the disjoint union of $B_1$ and $B_2$ where $B_1$ and $B_2$ are closed in $X$ and $Y$ respectively ?

Comment: @Victor: Yes, it is. Suppose that $F$ is closed in $X\cup Y$. Each of the sets $X$ and $Y$ is closed in $X\cup Y$, so $F\cap X$ and $F\cap Y$ are closed in $X\cup Y$, and clearly $F$ is the disjoint union of these two sets.

Comment: Seems like i have stopped thinking,i need my coffee : ) Anyway,Thank you.Give me some time to digest your solution!

Comment: @Victor: You’re welcome; take whatever time you need!

Comment: Thank you,i understand your solution!

Comment: @Victor: You’re welcome; glad to help!